# Merge two csvfiles by column header

Tags: command-line, text-processing, scripting, awk, csv

I have two csv files:

#### success.csv

*"ID","Legacy ID","Field1", "Field2"*

```
1,1111,google,news
2,2222,yahoo,news
```

#### error.csv

*"Legacy ID","Field1","Field2","Message"*

```
3333,aol,news,"Failed to upload data"    
4444,cbs,news,"Alredy exists"
```

How can I merge these two files and create a new file as shown below? I cannot use indexes as the size and order of fields will keep changing.

#### results.csv

*"ID","Legacy ID","Message"*

```
1,1111,""
2,2222,""
"",3333,"Failed to upload data"
"",4444,"Alredy exists"
```

The requirement is to create the `results.csv` file with only three columns from both `success.csv` and `error.csv`.

1. If the row is successfully loaded then we get "ID" in the success file as the first column with no "Message" Column
2. If it's failed we get an error in the "Message" field which is always the last field in the file. In this case the "ID" will be empty.

Read the values from `success.csv` as follows:

```
awk '{print $1, $2;}' success.csv
```

Read the values from `error.csv` as follows:

```
awk '{print $1, NF;}' error.csv
```

I am not able to figure out a way to combine both the statements and write the result to a file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you get to `results.csv` from the first two files. You seem to be removing some information, why and how can we know? Also, please show us what you have tried and how it has failed. We're happy to _help_ you but we won't do all the work for you.

Comment: CSV files can have (quoted) fields with newlines, you should use a real library as available for Python, Perl, etc. to parse these files and extract the fields you need.

Comment: I guess there is a typo in `awk '{print $1, NF;}' error.csv`. That shall probably be `awk '{print $1, $NF;}' error.csv`. And in both cases you need `awk -F, ...`

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, but I believe you are looking for the following construct:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{print $1,$2,"\"\"";next}{print "\"\"",$1,$NF}' success.csv error.csv
```

Explanation:

- first of all at the very beginning we set field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) to `,`
- we process both files in one go, but we check which one is processed. The first one is processed when current row number is equal to current row number in current file (`NR==FNR`).
- so for first file (`success.csv`) we print `$1,$2,"\"\""` while for second (`error.csv`) we print `"\"\"",$1,$NF`.

The result is:

```
1,1111,""
2,2222,""
"",3333,"Failed to upload data"    
"",4444,"Alredy exists"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
$ mlr --csv unsparsify then cut -f ID,'Legacy ID',Message  success.csv error.csv
ID,Legacy ID,Message
1,1111,
2,2222,
,3333,Failed to upload data
,4444,Alredy exists
```

This uses the "unsparsify" operation of Miller to merge the data from the two files based on the available headers, and to assign empty strings as values that does not exist for a particular header in a file. A "cut" operation is then perform to extract only a subset of the fields.

The order of the fields depend on the order in which Miller finds them, so you get a different ordering if you give the file in the opposite order:

```bash
$ mlr --csv unsparsify then cut -f ID,'Legacy ID',Message  error.csv success.csv
Legacy ID,Message,ID
3333,Failed to upload data,
4444,Alredy exists,
1111,,1
2222,,2
```

You may reorder the fields in an explicit order with the "reorder" operation after "cut", to not be dependent on the order of the fields in the input files:

```bash
mlr --csv \
    unsparsify then \
    cut -f ID,'Legacy ID',Message then \
    reorder -f ID,'Legacy ID',Message \
    error.csv success.csv
```